# How encryption and decryption by symmetric key using ecdh key in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I read about hybrid cryptosystems in some books.  public-key cryptography is used to secure and distribute session keys like ecdh algorithm ; those session keys are used with symmetric algorithms like Aes to secure message traffic. The idea from this method enhancing performance better than public algorithm ok. 
I searched about any example use ecdh with any symmetric algorithm by java language but I don't find.
I need any link or book has any hybrid algorithm use ecdh with symmatric algorithm.
also Is hybrid cryptosystems better than public cryptosystems? If yes? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid and public cryptography supplement each other. As they are different concepts there is little need for direct comparison.

As for a good example for DH together with symmetric keys you could take a look at implementation of ECDH cipher suites in Java TLS implementations.